# How do I mitigate the risk of an infinite loop?

Tags: c#, infinite-loop, enumerator

We are looking through our code trying to identify high CPU usage, and I am looking at several areas where we use while loops. I would like to take the risk of infinite loops out of the code shown below, but I am not sure what the best solution would be.

```
IDictionaryEnumerator codeEnumerator = Resources.Error_Codes.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true).GetEnumerator();
IDictionaryEnumerator messageEnumerator = Resources.Error_Messages.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true).GetEnumerator();


bool codeDone = false;
bool messageDone = false;

while (codeEnumerator.MoveNext() && !codeDone)
{
    string value = codeEnumerator.Value.ToString();
    if (value == failedResponse.Code.ToString())
    {
        key = codeEnumerator.Key.ToString();
        codeDone = true;
    }
}

while (messageEnumerator.MoveNext() && !messageDone)
{
    if (messageEnumerator.Key.ToString() == key)
    {
        message = messageEnumerator.Value.ToString();
        messageDone = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code with more care next time to avoid horizontal scrolling where possible. There's no point in having the code start half way across the screen.

Comment: Are you worried about the sequences being infinite sequences, or are you worried about the code running forever even if the sequences are finite?

Comment: The resources in each of the resource sets that are being enumerated are finite. It may not even be possible for their to be an infinite loop in the code above, but I want to be sure.

Comment: I don't see how you can get infinite loops with your code. Could you explain a little better your question?

Comment: Is there some reason you're opposed to using a `foreach` loop to iterate the sequences?

Comment: @NikolaDavidovic You may be right, it is possible that an infinite loop is not possible. I am just trying to determine that, and if there is a safer way to do this. If I can rule this area as not possible for infinite loops, that is a success!

Comment: Start by making the code *correct*. I'm not seeing any Dispose() calls in that code. **You are required to dispose enumerators**; if you do not then the finally blocks in the iterator blocks will never run. I would consider rewriting this incorrect code to use a sequence operators; that will make the code correct, shorter and easier to read.

Comment: "Part of the reason we are going through and modifying code is to reduce overall CPU usage" You have a tight loop, which will ramp CPU usage up if the list is long enough.  You could technically reduce CPU usage in the loop by placing a **small** call to Sleep() in the while loops (small like maybe 50); but to what end?  This will make the loops run **longer**, though, which isn't really "better".  There's a trade-off between CPU usage and time to complete the task!  Can you access the Dictionaries directly?...the second loop would be un-necessary since you've found the key in the first loop.

Comment: Moreover: suppose the first loop fails to find a key. In the second loop you *search for that key*, but you never filled in what the key was in the first place.

Comment: Moreover: Why are you searching *a dictionary* by looping over it?  **The whole point of a dictionary is that you can search it directly**, that's why its called a dictionary.  Infinite loops are the least of your problems here; this code is deeply flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the underlying sequence are finite, not infinite, ([which you have said is the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304452/how-do-i-mitigate-the-risk-of-an-infinite-loop#comment23342949_16304452)) then the loops will not run forever.

Eventually you can be sure that one of the following things will happen:

1. The `if` will be true for a given item, thus setting the boolean and breaking out of the loop.
2. You will advance to the end of the sequence, thus resulting in `MoveNext` being false.
3. An exception will be thrown from somewhere, such as from the underlying collection being modified by another thread, by a null value in the sequence, or anything else.  As you have no try/catch, this will break you out of the loop.

In particular, since each iteration of the loop *must* advance the iterator (due to `MoveNext`) you can be sure that you will eventually end.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and trying to figure out what your dictionaries are actually named, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
var key = Error_Codes.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value.ToString = 
    failedResponse.Code.ToString()).Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
string message = string.Empty;
if(null != key)
    message = Error_Messages[key];
```

This assumes your dictionaries are Error_Codes and Error_Messages.

As Eric pointed out in the comments, there were issues with the way you were using iterators and dictionaries. This does away with the iterator problems, but this still isn't an ideal way to use dictionaries.

If you have a unique list of error messages and error code keys, then you could have a dictionary that maps the two together. Alternatively, you could combine the dictionaries with a common key set for the dictionary key, and a tuple of error codes and error messages as the dictionary values.

Answer (score -1):

You could start a timer/other thread that sets a second contidion to false if the loop takes more than x time. But i dont think that this is a clean solution either.

Comment: Part of the reason we are going through and modifying code is to reduce overall CPU usage, so I'm not sure spawning additional timer or thread would be helpful in the long run. Thanks tho!

Answer (score -2):

You could add a counter that counts down in the while loop. Set the counter real high to a value like 100 or so and When the counter reaches zero, exit the loop. It means that its possible it might terminate before the operation is completely carried out, but it means it will eventually exit.